# why Flutter App doesn't work on real device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, apk

I have been working on an app which has been working fine on the emulator. Today I tried to export my app and install the app on an Android device. At first the app seemed to be fine. The homepage works correctly and the four buttons (RawMaterialButton) on the homepage also work. When I press one of the buttons it redirects to a different page which also contains a button (floatactionbutton). But this button unfortunately doesn't do anything. I don't understand why, on the emulator everything is fine but on a real Android device it doesn't work!

I tried replacing the button on the second page with the (working) button from the homepage. Also without result!

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: If you can link the github repo, or add the code will be helpful

Comment: please add error message. it will be shown on your IDE

Comment: Please add the code. There might be a trillion mistakes that could lead to this kind of issue. For example, `Navigator.pushNamed` if `onGenerateRoute` returns null, would lead to an error in debug version, but wouldn't do anything in release version.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2591

Comment: @jun I dont see any error message showing. Its something with the if statements that keep giving the error. in the github link from above is the code. Thanks everyone

Comment: @jun i dont see any error message showing on my IDE while using the app on my device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mistake in your code in the github link.
As you sait, when you remove the if statement, it worked.The probleme come from your if statement that is probably false:

```
if(checkBookingID(reservationCodeInput.text)){
Navigator.push(context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => ChangeThemeOption())
);
```

Can't give more help without more code

Comment: The if statement was correct but the checkBooking needs to get some data from the server but this wasn't working. Fixed it with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  in the manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i fixed it with adding

in my manifest.xml

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>